# Which thesaurus best describes the differences between several similar words?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms, resources, online-resources

Which thesaurus (online or paper) best describes the differences between several similar words? As a non-native English speaker, it is often difficult for me to distinguish the slightly different concepts in similar words. I'm looking for a good online dictionary or thesaurus that compares those synonyms word by word.

Answer (score 3):

I use the **Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus**.

But well, many online dictionaries provide synonymous terms, even if they are not specifically Thesaurus.

For example, the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/) sometimes provides synonyms for the terms you search. In such cases it shows the differences in *meaning* and, above all, in *usage*. But this is not always the case, unfortunately.

Comment: the last sentence is ambiguous. also, you could make the first one link when it gets more attention.

Comment: @zizi: Sentence improved.

Comment: The first one can't be linked, it's in my computer. About the second, I'm not aware of any limit about adverbs' use.

Comment: problem solved! I didn't say it's false, i smelled problems!

Answer (score 3):

if you actually subscribe to [Howard Gardner's Theory of Multiple Intelligences](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/) and want your synonyms and antonyms "described" to you in pictures, then check out the [Visual Thesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/). Here's an example using "articulate":
[image: the word "articulate" in The Visual Thesaurus]

Answer (score 2):

I found a good reference [here](http://www.visualthesaurus.com). You can simply use Google by the way.

Answer (score 2):

[WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn) is very good indeed for this, and other kinds of questions like this, because it was constructed specifically for that purpose. In their own words:

> WordNet superficially resembles a thesaurus, in that it groups words together based on their meanings. However, there are some important distinctions. First, WordNet interlinks not just word forms—strings of letters—but specific senses of words. As a result, words that are found in close proximity to one another in the network are semantically disambiguated.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/) for me has the most advantages. It gives approximately 20 synonyms every time I search for a word. And because it's on the internet and free, it is easily accessible, all the time.

Comment: nothing is accessible all the time.

Comment: A list of synonyms alone isn't quite helpful. Often, I was disappointed by the circular definition of those synonyms.

Comment: the thing about this website is it's kind of combined with a dictionary, so any time you are unsure as to the meaning, just search under a different section.